# Get all values in a hash from string after equals sign Perl

Tags: perl

I have a string like this `"Test string has tes value like abc="123",bcd="345",or it it can be xyz="4567" and ytr="434""`.

Now what i want to get the values after equals sign.The hash structure while be like this :

```
$hash->{abc} =123,
$hash->{bcd} =345,
$hash->{xyz} =4567,
```

i have tried this `$str =~ / (\S+) \s* = \s* (\S+) /xg`

Comment: So what exactly do you have trouble with? I think what you want to do is parse the string, find all pairs of `word="number"` and assign them to hashes. By the way, your string isn't valid Perl, because you have nested unescaped double quotes `""`.

Comment: Show us, What have you tried so far? Its can be solved with simple regex.

Comment: @Developer: Okay, and what is wrong with what you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex returns the captured pairs, which can be assigned to a hash, made anonymous.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $str = 'Test string has tes value like abc="123",bcd="345",or it '
        . 'it can be xyz="4567" and ytr="434"';    

my $rh = { $str =~ /(\w+)="(\d+)"/g }

say "$_ => $rh->{$_}" for keys %$rh ;
```

Prints

```
bcd => 345
abc => 123
ytr => 434
xyz => 4567
```

---

Following a comment – for possible spaces around the `=` sign, change it to `\s*=\s*`.

Comment: $VAR1 = {} no data in $rh

Comment: how can we ignore the spaces

Comment: I don't understand -- ignore what spaces?

Comment: spaces between abc = "1234"

Comment: @Developer Oh, you mean if there were spaces?  Add optional multiple spaces to regex, `\s*=\s*` (instead of just `=`)

Comment: @Developer: Are you saying that there are spaces in your real data that you haven't shown us in your sample data? You can't expect to get useful answers if your test data doesn't cover all possibilities :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my $string = q{Test string has tes value like abc="123",bcd="345" and xyz="523"};
my %hash = $string =~ /(\w+)="(\d*)"/g;
print Dumper \%hash;
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'xyz' => '523',
          'abc' => '123',
          'bcd' => '345'
        };
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/nJFLml)

Answer (score 0):

Your test string looks like this (editing slightly to fix the quoting problems).

```
'Test string has tes value like abc="123",bcd="345",or it it can be xyz="4567" and ytr="434"'
```

I used this code to test your regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;

my $text = 'Test string has tes value like abc="123",bcd="345",or it it can be xyz="4567" and ytr="434"';

my %hash = $text =~ /(\S+)\s*=\s*(\S+)/g;

say Dumper \%hash;
```

Which gives this output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'abc="123",bcd' => '"345",or'
          'ytr' => '"434"',
          'xyz' => '"4567"'
        };
```

The problem is that `\S+` matches any non-whitespace character. And that's too much. You need to be more descriptive about the valid characters.

Your keys appear to all be letters. And your values are all digits - but they are surrounded by quote characters that you don't want. So try this regex instead = `/([a-z]+)\s*=\s*"(\d+)"/g`.

That gives:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'bcd' => '345',
          'abc' => '123',
          'ytr' => '434',
          'xyz' => '4567'
        };
```

Which looks correct to me.